# How to label histograms?

Tags: statistics

I got some homework, where we have to label histograms, and I don't get a few things.

1,If the classes are labeled like: 0-40 and 40-80 then how should I tell the class boundaries? 0-40.5 and 39.5-80.5? And how can I put this on a histogram, since 2 classes interfere with each other?

2,If I have the class boundaries in a 'proper way' :
0-40.5 and 40.5-80.5 -for the classes 0-40 and 41-80 respectively, then should I label the first class in the 0-40 and the second class in the 40-80 part of the histogram, or I should go a bit further with each class, and do it from 0-40.5 and 40.5-80.5? Or that' not important in a histogram to label it like that? 
2,b And should I write -0.5-40.5 for the first class?>further in Q3

3,My teacher said something about making a class boundary for e.g a class 0-40 as -0.5-40.5. Is that possible every time? Because now i got an exercise which says label the length of phone calls in a histogram, and the first class is 0-2.5, now I can't write a phone calls duration is -0.5 minutes.. In what cases can I use -0.5 as a boundary?

Answer (score 2):

Warning: your teacher might not like this answer.

The purpose of a histogram is to provide a visual summary of a large data set. That's why you collect the instances into ranges. For example, for annual family income you might use the ranges \$0-\$10K, \$10K-\$20K and so on. Since there are lots of families and the number with income exactly \$10K is small (probably 0) the picture will be the same wherever you count that family. Labeling the first range \$0-\$9,999.99 would make the choice unambiguous, but would be visually very confusing.

My answer: in a real situation the question is irrelevant. But that may not be true in made up situations in your class.